# How do I define a variable which is a sequential list of integers in gmake?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Given a variable `MAX`, how do I create a variable `LIST` which contains the integers 1 to `$(MAX)`?

Using `shell` or similar is not possible for my context.

Comment: I needed this to solve a real problem and couldn't find the answer elsewhere. This sounds like code golf because gmake is such a restricted language. My wording about "cheating", which I've since changed, didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good, though you don't need the `$eval`:

```
seq = $(if $(filter $1,$(words $2)),$2,$(call seq,$1,$2 $(words $2)))
$(error [$(call seq,10)])
```

or somesuch. Make will complain `warning: undefined variable '2'` under `--warn`, but you can avoid that by using `$(value…)`.

[You probably want `$(filter…)` rather than `$(findstring…)`in your solution BTW.]

Comment: You've eliminated the growing sequence of "x"s, which is also nice. I wanted to start with 1, so I needed to modify your version slightly:  `seq = $(strip $(if $(filter $1,$(words $2)),$2,$(call seq,$1,$2 $(words $2 x))))`. Why is `filter` better than `findstring` in this context?

Comment: @MatthewSimoneau Actually it probably has worse memory performance. Although it doesn't have a sequence of "x"s, it does have the stack frames of the recursive call to deal with, and the "local variables". I suspect `0`, `0 1`, `0 1 2` ... `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` are all in memory at once (not sure, just a suspicion)

Comment: @MatthewSimoneau `$(findstring …)` would find the `50` in `1501`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clumsy solution using `eval`:

```
UPTO = $(eval TEMP += $(words $(2))) \
       $(if $(findstring $(1),$(words $(2))),$(TEMP),$(call UPTO,$(1),$(2) x))
SEQUENCE_TO = $(eval TEMP := )$(strip $(call UPTO,$(1),x))

MAX := 50
LIST := $(call SEQUENCE_TO,$(MAX))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple recursive solution, I find it somewhat more understandable than the `$(words ...)` solution although I guess in the end they're not that different.  For better or for worse, this is certainly more verbose.

The repeated call to `$(wordlist 2,...)` is a bit of a wart.  Maybe it could be avoided.

```
count = $(call count0,$1,0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
count0 = $(if $(wordlist $1,$1,$(wordlist 2,1000000,$2)), \
        $(wordlist 1,$1,$(wordlist 2,1000000,$2)), \
        $(patsubst 0%,%,$(call count0,$1,$(patsubst %,0%,$2) \
                $(patsubst %,1%,$2) $(patsubst %,2%,$2) $(patsubst %,3%,$2) \
                $(patsubst %,4%,$2) $(patsubst %,5%,$2) $(patsubst %,6%,$2) \
                $(patsubst %,7%,$2) $(patsubst %,8%,$2) $(patsubst %,9%,$2))))

.PHONY: nst
nst:
        @echo 7: $(call count,7)
        @echo 51: $(call count,51)
        @echo 111: $(call count,111)
```